# Where is wifi on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, wireless

Thanks for your help in with my installation issue! 
Now I can't figure out how to connect with wifi. 
I can connect with an ethernet cord.

Comment: Click on the network button above the desktop,you will see available WiFi hotspots.Click on the suitable hotspot and connect.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's blocked when you first install Ubuntu.  If that's the case open a Terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) window and enter the following commands:

```
rfkill unblock all
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
sudo reboot
```

After a restart it should be work. The next issue you may run into is that wifi is ridiculously slow, which I'm trying to deal with as well.